# How can I review OSS license status of node_modules in my app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, open-source

My companies web UI app is React/Redux/Node based.  node_modules has some 900 directories in it. Before we release the app, Legal wants a review of the license status of all Open Source Software included, both server and UI.

What is an easy way to review the license type for all of the Node packages? "open each README, find the license, figure out what type it is, note it down, open next README..." is not a fun suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`license-checker`](https://github.com/davglass/license-checker).

```
$ npm install -g license-checker
$ cd project/
$ license-checker
```

It then gives you a list of all dependencies and their licenses, e.g.:

```
├─ cli@0.4.3
│  ├─ repository: http://github.com/chriso/cli
│  └─ licenses: MIT
```

Comment: Wonderful, this is exactly what I needed.  Many thanks!